# GraphQL get a user with GraphQL tools

Tags: node.js, graphql

I have a GraphQL server using ExpressJS. This is the schema using GraphQL-Tools:

```
import UserModel from '../models/User'

export const Schema =  `

type User {
    id: Int!
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
}

type Query {
    users: [User]
}

schema {
    query: Query
}

`

export const resolveFunctions = {
    Query: {
        users() {
            return UserModel.findAll()
        }
    }
}
```

Without GraphQL-Tools I'm able to get full list of users and a certain user but now when I'm using GraphQL-Tools I have no idea how to get a certain user by id.

I didn't find any resources online on GraphQL tools except the official documentation, so I hope this will help other people who are finding an answer.

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a query:

```
user(id: String!): User
```

and the handler:

```
user(root, args, ctx) {
  return UserModel.findOne({id: args.id});
}
```

(you might need to adjust the parameter types and the call semantics, I just outlined the required steps).

If you'd like to see a working example, you can have a look at a [graphQL starter project](https://github.com/DxCx/webpack-apollo-server). I recently added to it a very similar query.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should have a look at [graphqly](https://github.com/anhldbk/graphqly). It's an abstraction built on top of `graphql-tools` that help you develop Graphql services easier. Here's the sample code with `graphqly`:

```
import graphly from "graphqly";

const gBuilder = graphly.createBuilder();

// define types, inputs ... (in any order)
gBuilder.type("Products").implements("List").def(`
    products: [Product]!
`);

gBuilder.type("Product").def(`
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    link: String
    price: Int
`);

gBuilder
.query(`
    products(limit: Int = 20, offset: Int = 0, filter: ProductFilter): Products
`)
.resolve((root, args, context) => {
    // your resolver here
});
```